How to make compiler warning about the enum type mismatch in switch and case?
For the following code, I hope there is a warning because a is type enum A, but the case B1 and B2 are type enum B; but I couldn't find a way to make gcc/clang warn about it.
Any suggestion on how to detect the potential bugs like this?
Thanks
enum A { A1, A2 };

enum B { B1, B2 };

int foo(enum A a) {
        switch(a) {
                case B1:
                        return 1;
                case B2:
                        return 2;
                default:
                        return 3;
        }
}


$ clang -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Werror -c enum3.c; echo $?
0
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Werror -c enum3.c; echo $?
0
$ clang --version
Ubuntu clang version 14.0.0-1ubuntu1.1
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.



Leave off the default: and the compiler will warn you (with -Wall) if you omit a case:

I'm not sure how you can do this in C, but FYI you can do it in C++ using enum class  types: example C++ code.

I am loathe to answer, because I don’t actually know... but I suspect there isn’t a way. In C, enums are essentially what C++ would call named constexprs.

Nothing I can find in GCC’s documentation addresses it, and the ones that looked iffy I tried. Sorry.

The tokens you've shown already indicate their type (A of A1 and A2). Welcome to C. Coders shoulder responsibility. Don't be lazy and casual, relying on a super-sophisticated compiler to warn you about things you should be paying attention to. C is an old language. Accept it for what it is...

Speaking of things I know vanishing little about: If you feel this represents something you want/need from a language, perhaps try Rust instead of C. (Intended to be helpful; not to be sarcastic.)

It appears clang warns about this by default in  C++ mode, but unfortunately won't warn about it at all in C.  Here's the use and definition of the function that does the check, but it will take someone more familiar with the compiler to say why it doesn't work in C. From looking at similar diagnostics that do work in C it seems feasible to add though.

Misc tips & tricks here: How to create type safe enums?

As others have noted, there does not appear to be any
warning built in to GCC or Clang to do this when compiling as C, although Kevin points out in a comment that -Wenum-compare-switch, which is enabled by default, will warn about this in C++ mode.  There is also no
clang-tidy
check for it.
However, it is possible to write a check condition for this using
clang-query.
The following check will report any switch whose condition expression
has enumeration type, and it has a case that has a case constant that
has a different enumeration type:
#!/bin/sh

PATH=$HOME/opt/clang+llvm-16.0.0-x86_64-linux-gnu-ubuntu-18.04/bin:$PATH

# In this query, the comments are stripped by a 'grep' command further
# below.  (clang-query also ignores comments, but its mechanism is
# a little buggy.)
query='m
  # Look for a "switch" statement
  switchStmt(
    # where its condition expression
    hasCondition(
      # after skipping past any implicit casts
      ignoringImpCasts(
        # is an expression
        expr(
          # whose type
          hasType(
            # after stripping typedefs, etc.,
            hasUnqualifiedDesugaredType(
              # is an enumeration
              enumType(
                # whose declaration
                hasDeclaration(
                  # is an enumeration declaration.  Bind that
                  # declaration to the name "switch-enum".
                  enumDecl().bind("switch-enum")
                )
              )
            )
          )
        )
      )
    ),

    # Furthermore, having found a relevant "switch", examine each of its
    # "case" and "default" statements and report any that
    forEachSwitchCase(
      # is a "case" statement
      caseStmt(
        # whose constant expression
        hasCaseConstant(
          # has any descendant
          hasDescendant(
            # that is a reference to a declaration
            declRefExpr(
              # where that declaration
              hasDeclaration(
                # is an enumerator declaration
                enumConstantDecl(
                  # whose parent
                  hasParent(
                    # is an enumeration declaration
                    enumDecl(
                      # unless
                      unless(
                        # that enumeration is the same one that we found
                        # when matching the "switch" condition.
                        equalsBoundNode("switch-enum")
                      )
                    )
                  )
                ).bind("case-enumerator")
              )
            )
          )
        )
      ).bind("case-stmt")
    )
  ).bind("switch")
'

# Strip the comments.
query=$(echo "$query" | egrep -v '^ +#')

if [ "x$1" = "x" ]; then
  echo "usage: $0 filename.c -- <compile options like -I, etc.>"
  exit 2
fi

# Run the query.  Setting 'bind-root' to false means clang-query will
# not also print a redundant "root" binding where I have bound "switch".
clang-query \
  -c="set bind-root false" \
  -c="$query" \
  "$@"

# EOF

When run on this input:
// test.c
// Testing mismatched switch(enum).

enum A { A1, A2 };

enum B { B1, B2 };

int f(enum A a)
{
  switch (a) {
    case B1:       // reported
      return 1;
    case B2:       // reported
      return 2;
    default:
      return 3;
  }
}

int f2(enum A a)
{
  switch (a) {
    case 1:        // not reported
      return 1;
    case 3:        // not reported (but clang -Wswitch warns)
      return 3;
    case A1:       // not reported: correct enumeration
      return B2;   // not reported: not in the 'case' constant expr
    default:
      return B2;   // not reported: not in a 'case'
  }
}

typedef enum A AAlias;

int f3(AAlias a)
{
  // Make sure we do not get confused by a typedef.
  switch (a) {
    case B1:       // reported
      return 1;
    default:
      return 0;
  }
}

// EOF

it produces this output:
$ ./cmd.sh test.c --
$(PWD)/test.c:25:10: warning: case value not in enumerated type 'enum A' [-Wswitch]
    case 3:        // not reported (but clang -Wswitch warns)
         ^

Match #1:

$(PWD)/test.c:6:14: note: "case-enumerator" binds here
enum B { B1, B2 };
             ^~
$(PWD)/test.c:13:5: note: "case-stmt" binds here
    case B2:       // reported
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
$(PWD)/test.c:10:3: note: "switch" binds here
  switch (a) {
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~
$(PWD)/test.c:4:1: note: "switch-enum" binds here
enum A { A1, A2 };
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Match #2:

$(PWD)/test.c:6:10: note: "case-enumerator" binds here
enum B { B1, B2 };
         ^~
$(PWD)/test.c:11:5: note: "case-stmt" binds here
    case B1:       // reported
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
$(PWD)/test.c:10:3: note: "switch" binds here
  switch (a) {
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~
$(PWD)/test.c:4:1: note: "switch-enum" binds here
enum A { A1, A2 };
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Match #3:

$(PWD)/test.c:6:10: note: "case-enumerator" binds here
enum B { B1, B2 };
         ^~
$(PWD)/test.c:40:5: note: "case-stmt" binds here
    case B1:       // reported
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
$(PWD)/test.c:39:3: note: "switch" binds here
  switch (a) {
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~
$(PWD)/test.c:4:1: note: "switch-enum" binds here
enum A { A1, A2 };
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
3 matches.

For more details on what the elements of the query do, see the Clang
AST Matcher Reference.
It's pretty terse though, so trial and error is required to make use of
it.
FWIW, I ran this over a couple large-ish C++ translation units I had
at hand and it didn't report anything.  So while I haven't really done
any "tuning" of the query it appears to not explode with noise.
Of course, adding a custom clang-query command to your build is much
more work than just adding a compiler warning option, but it's perhaps
something to experiment with at least.

So you can write ad-hoc warnings using a tool for C programming langauge?! Finally! Would you mind me asking you an unrelated question? Is it possible to implement printf-like warnings for format specifier vs types mismatches using clang-query?

@KamilCuk Checking format strings is unfortunately beyond what clang-query can do because the matchers cannot look at string literals.  For that, you would need to write something using the Clang C++ API, which is called  libtooling.  That is also the name of an SO tag you could use to ask questions if you try it and run into trouble.

Any decent static analyser will warn for this (clang-tidy might not be one) without the user having to write some script. Enum type safety is a requirement for MISRA compliance, so a static analyser with MISRA checking will solve the problem. Preferably one that isn't hopelessly broken.


Any suggestion on how to detect the potential bugs like this?

You can't, at least not in standard C.
enums are a very weak abstraction in C; they're a way to introduce named integer constants and not much more. enums don't create their own namespaces, there aren't any constraints against assigning a value of one enum type to a variable of another enum type, etc.  Enumeration constants belong to the "all other identifiers" namespace, so two different enumeration types can't use the same enumeration constants.
Do not expect C enumeration types to have the same type safety as enumeration types in Java or C#.

It's pretty common to create a coupling between an enum and a jump table, rather than using switch. You can create a bit better integrity between the enum and the jump table than what would otherwise be possible.
For example:
typedef enum : unsigned int // optionally use C23 enums here for better type safety
{
  A1,
  A2,
  A_n // the number of enumeration items
} A;

typedef int A_func_t (void);

int A1_func (void) { return 1; }
int A2_func (void) { return 2; }

A_func_t* const A_func[] =   // function pointer jump table
{
  [A1] = A1_func,
  [A2] = A2_func,
};

static_assert(sizeof A_func/sizeof *A_func == A_n, 
              "Enum does not correspond with jump table A_func");

...

int foo (A a) 
{
  if(a < 0 || a >= A_n) // optional range test/defensive programming, a<0 in case we use pre-C23 enums
  {
    halt_and_catch_fire();
  }

  return A_func[a]();
}

